# Can't import installed package

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my setup.py file to work correctly. I'm able to run the install command and everything appears to be working. I see all the appropriate files being copied to various locations and there aren't any error messages but when I actually try to import the package from the python command line I get errors saying it doesn't exist.

[image: Python install output]
[Larger picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElwCU.png)

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you do me a favor -- run `which python` and see what it says.

Comment: That results in `/home/pi/programming/python/passport-server/env/bin/python`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you cd out of the install directory, otherwise you'll get weird behaviour.  Also, if you run

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Make sure the module was installed to a location that is on your python path

Comment: That shows a lot of directories including `/home/pi/programming/python/passport-server/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages` which is where the install shows the `passport.py` file being copied.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's all the files to compiled in the picture, here is why all you tries failed.

1) You do not have a file named passport.phaseI. Imports must be mapped to a file.

2) Assuming you mean to import the Passport class in the passport/phase/passport file, you need to call it like: 
`from passport.phase.passport import Passport`

3) See number 1. You do not have a file named passport, but you do have a dir.

I think the code from number two is going to help you the best.

Edit: One more note: remember your `__init__.py` files in each folder.

Hope this helps!